# Dealing with a transparent png file symbol

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, click, transparent

In my project, there is a frame(png files) placed on the top of all symbols. After that,  I apply mouse click event to the symbols that place underneath the frame symbol, but when I run the the game, I cannot click to the below symbols but only the frame symbol, although the frame is transparent.

The problem is, although the png picture has some transparent area, the mouse click cannot pass through it. Is there solution? Is there anyway I can disable a symbol from being clicked and mouse click event can recognize the symbol placed under it? Could you help me? thx a lot ^0^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may put your png in a movieclip, give it a name (myFrame), and then write:

```
myFrame.mouseEnabled = false;
myFrame.mouseChildren = false;
```

Comment: mouseChildren is the equivalent of mouseEnabled but for every children of the clip.